# Android ListView Tutorial with onclick and images

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to make a listview having images on each row and if one item is clicked, user will be taken to another activity 
i have 26 activities-

Activity_a

Activity_b

Activity_c

Activity_d

and so on...

and i want to have alphabet images at each row (i already have the images)

i found this tutorial on http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1659127

Here is how my app should look like  http://www.imagesup.net/?di=413818360350

And here is my .java file

```
    package com.Rohit.MyApp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String[] items = { "Milk", "Butter", "Yogurt", "Toothpaste", "Ice Cream" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with yours?

Comment: If you are looking for custom ListView with image then [take a look here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

Answer (score 1):

You should only use one activity and start it with a bundle. 26 Activities is just plain wrong.

You can use an `OnItemSelectedListener` on the List view and start an activity with:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,ABCActivity.class);
i.putExtra("LETTER",selectedLetter);
startActivity(i);
```

That's assuming you figured out how to get the selectedLetter.

Comment: True. It is the best Way, otherwise its not a mobile app.

Comment: actually i wanted to have 26 activities having 100 words starting with a, b ,c ,and so on . and  more than 100 webview activities linked to each item in the above activities so there will be like 2600 activities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a good tutorial link on Custom Array Adapters, [here](http://stellarwavedev.com/2012/05/android-custom-arrayadapter-text-and-icon/) you go. And then just `setOnClickListener` for the image view. 
For good coding practice, don't ever use so many activities. Consider reusing some of them or use [Fragments](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: hey actually i wanted to have more than 100 activities in my project

Comment: Not at all recommended. It seems easy to work with a new activity for every screen but fragments give you more options. But keep in mind fragments are supported only above Honeycomb.